# Messages ending up in dead letter queue

Tags: java, akka, router, dead-letter

I have the following code

```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof newRequest) {

      ActorRef childRouter =
          getContext()
              .actorOf(
                  new SmallestMailboxPool(actorPoolSize)
                      .props(Props.create(ChildActor.class, param)),
                  "childActor");
      childActor.tell(new someOtherMessage(), getSelf());
    }
```

When a `newRequest` message is received, it is processed, But the child actor never recieves the `someOtherMessage()` and the `someOtherMessage` always ends up in the deadltter queue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `ChildActor` is never getting created?

Comment: do you handle someOtherMessage in your ChildActor actor (e.g. `return receiveBuilder().match(someOtherMessage.class, ...)`)?